# jquery Mobile: can't set button's left and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[Web app in progress is here](http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/school/musicQuiz/musicQuiz-staticKbds.html). **(corrected URL)**

I'm trying to develop a music-reading quiz game for my daughters, using jQuery Mobile.

The part I'm having trouble with is the keyboard.
With "ordinary" html buttons, you can set the left/top/width/height css properties using jQuery's `.css()` method. But with jQuery Mobile, that doesn't seem to work. Anybody know how to move buttons in jQuery Mobile?

Here's an excerpt of the initial HTML for the keyboard buttons:

```
<div id="kbdC2E" class="keyboard">
    <button class="pianoKey whiteKey" id="wk1" />
        <button class="pianoKey blackKey" id="bk1" />
    <button class="pianoKey whiteKey" id="wk2" />
        <button class="pianoKey blackKey" id="bk2" /> <!-- etc. -->
```

And here's the javascript code to move them into position:

```
for (i = 0; i < numWhiteKeys; i++) {
    var keyLeft = whiteKeyWidth * i;
    var $key = $('button#wk' + i, $div).parent();
    $key.addClass('pianoKey whiteKey')
    .css({
        // position: 'absolute', // from pianoKey class
        left: keyLeft,
        top: gap,
        width: whiteKeyWidth,
        height: whiteKeyHeight,
    });
```

Note that we use the **parent** of the `button#wk1` key, because jQuery Mobile has decorated our `<button>` HTML as:

```
<div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">...</span>
  <button class="pianoKey whiteKey ui-btn-hidden" id="wk1"></button>
</div>
```

(You can verify the details by going to [the web page](http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/school/musicQuiz/musicQuiz-staticKbds.html) and using a DOM/CSS inspector.)

When I run this, the result is that the parent div receives the added classes, by means of which it becomes position=relative; it also receives the top and height properties that I set:

```
<div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow pianoKey whiteKey"
     style="top: 72px; height: 90px; ">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">...</span>
  <button class="pianoKey whiteKey ui-btn-hidden" id="wk1"></button>
</div>
```

However it does not receive the "left" and "width" properties that I set.
As a result, all the keys end up on the left side of the ancestor div, and they have the wrong width. Can anybody tell me how to effectively set the left and width properties?

Thanks...

**P.S. update:** For an illustration of what I want the result to look like, see [here](http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/school/musicQuiz/musicQuiz.html). This is not the mechanism I want to use, because by adding buttons at run time, it apparently bypasses JQM completely, thus losing the touch-friendly and cross-platform benefits I'm trying to get from JQM. But it shows the layout I want.

Comment: Oops! I had the wrong URL there at first. Now it's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding the "px" to the width number? pretty much something like that:

```
.css({
    // position: 'absolute', // from pianoKey class
    left: keyLeft + 'px',
    top: gap,
    width: whiteKeyWidth +'px',
    height: whiteKeyHeight +'px',
});
```

I'm assuming that whiteKeyHeight and whiteKeyWidth are well declared and you made sure of that using alert().  Also, on another note (oh what a funny joke here), you should not use position absolute this might cause some problems in different browser/resolution etc.  You can use position relative to set the "left" attribute.  Also, the float left seems to be the best answer since it all does that for you without the need to add any code but the class using the "float: left;" attribute.

Comment: @Bene, thanks for your suggestions. Yes I've checked the value of whiteKeyWidth. But I just checked it again, and ... it was NaN!! And when I fixed it, setting `left` and `width` worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: Just to answer your other comments... Re: adding 'px', it didn't help, which was not surprising because setting `top`/`height` is already effective without 'px'. Re: position=absolute causing problems: can you give links to more info about this? I thought absolute-inside-relative was *the* way to accomplish this.

Comment: Re: 'use position relative to set the "left" attribute': that would place each button relative to where it "would" fall in the normal flow, right? which is where, right after the previous one? Re: float left: what would that do? I don't see how that could provide proper spacing for black keys.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the 'px' issue I actually thought i was right about this one.  The float: left properties is the best way to align multiple blocks on the same line but since your not actually "aligning" those notes, this doesn'T apply.  Finally, I see you did fine using the position: absolute attribute.  The point was that position: relative is almost the same as absolute but uses the parent container'S position instead of the viewport of the browser.  In case you wanted to "move" those notes, you could just have moved the container <div>, for example, making it much more easier.

Comment: @Bene, I've read the web page you referenced, and it doesn't say that relative means relative to the parent; it says it means relative to where the element would be in normal flow. I think what you're thinking of is absolute inside relative (which the about.com page doesn't mention); see http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ Anyway, thanks again for the valuable assist.

Comment: Oh my bad.  Guess i'm still new to CSS :P  I'll stay in jQuery mode then.  Thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to the question, as I belive that your values are just being rewritten due to the order in which scripts are being run, but

I suggest using `div` elements instead of buttons. Adding some classes to those divs will make them look as jquerymobile-ish as you want, and they don't need to be buttons at all... unless you want the application to be working without javascript too (I can't verify that at the moment)

[edit]

The second thing turned out a bit ambiguous... I'll elaborate.

I expect JQM to block or overwrite what you set. This can be avoided by reducing the ammount of JQM code that processes the buttons.

Inspect the buttins and copy most of their classes (this will give you the looks) and give those classes to some divs instead of button elements. Add your styles. Bind `tap` or `click` (I didn't see any bindings in your code at the moment) to get them to work - the same way you would have to do with buttons.

This is not a less-jqm-alike way to do that, you want to use relative positions and overlay buttons over other buttons - this is rather unusual, and so it needs unusual handling.

**Another idea:**

Have you seen this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html
or this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html
?

Maybe you don't have to position the buttons with position:relative at all (it's always a bit messy) just stick them together in two rows or stick pairs together as a column and set `float:left` on their wrappers. See what suits you

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the order in which scripts are being run"? Clearly my js code to move the parent div is running after jquery mobile restructures the DOM; we know this because the added parent of each button element is receiving the classes and top/height properties we gave it. What script do you think is running after that?

Comment: Re: your second paragraph, are you basically suggesting not use jQuery mobile? I wanted to get the cross-platform touch-friendly benefits on jQuery Mobile, but maybe that could be sacrificed if it makes DHTML too difficult.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure, but it is possible that those missing attributes are removed/overwritten and that's it. Just a guess

2. I'm not suggesting that - you should use classes that jqm brings in and implement clicks/taps just like you do now, but on simple div elements, not buttons. I bet your buttins don't work without javascript, so changing them to divs changes nothing for the javascript.

Comment: @naugtur, thanks for responding... you're the only one who's given it a try so far. Re: 2, what is to be gained by using divs instead of buttons? Are you hoping jqm won't "decorate" them or run scripts on them if they're divs? Seems to me if I'm bypassing two much of how jqm works, I might as well not use jqm.

Comment: @2 You still don't get it. ;) I'm just advising you to use different html objects. You will have to give them jqm specific classes and use click/tap events to write the support. It's as jqm-needy as it was, but if you don't want jqm to control the way the buttons are aligned, you have to make them not be buttons. It's time I edited the post ;)

Comment: @naugtur, I think I am understanding your suggestion (2). You propose divs so that jqm won't process my buttons as buttons. I see how this would hopefully stop jqm from stopping my left/width settings. But it also means I don't get the touch-friendly and cross-platform benefits of jqm relevant to buttons. In which case, the hassle of using a library that modifies my DOM structure in undocumented ways, and then having to modify that brittle structure by hand, doesn't seem worth it. However (next comment)

Comment: Regarding grouped buttons, I think they're just a different markup variant of what I've got; JQM would still control their layout. Same with navbar. Unless you have reason to think otherwise? Your last paragraph about wrappers, I didn't completely understand -- what difference would `float: left` make? However it gave me the idea of each key (button) being in its own div; then I could position each div, and let each key be a native jQM button within its div!

Comment: Bummer... the latter idea, of putting each button in its own div, didn't work... the divs receive the `top` and `height` css properties, but not the `left` and `width` ones. Tested this at http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/school/musicQuiz/musicQuiz-staticKbds2.html

Comment: I wanted to suggest that you use grouped buttons as the whole thing. They get aligned one by one quite well. Then you can put two rows over ewach other with `top` and it's ready.

Comment: @naugtur: So you're saying one group for the black keys and one for the white keys? This could work for the white keys, if it would let me set the width, which it doesn't; but the black keys need to be separated from each other, by irregular distances. How to accomplish that? margins?

Comment: Black keys (if it's apiano) have regular distances. Only some of the black keys are "missing". You can put empty transparent elements there and use the same margins for every element.

Comment: @naugtur: It's a valid point that we could think of black keys as being regularly spaced but "missing" keys between B/C and E/F. (This is not the spacing on a traditional keyboard, but it's good enough for this app.) But regularity is not the problem: the problem is how to force their position when I can't set the `left` or `width` properties. I will try setting the margins and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not functioning but is this what you wanted the key layout to do: http://jsfiddle.net/rg4wj/13/

Comment: when I go to that link, I see no javascript, and the buttons are all lined up side-by-side. Is that what you intended? No that's not what I wanted the key layout to do... I want the white keys (id="wk1" etc.) to be lower, and the black keys to be higher, as at http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/school/musicQuiz/musicQuiz.html but I want them spread out horizontally like piano keys, where the black key buttons partially overlap (and are in front of) the white keys. I had a working non-jqm prototype to show but it's not working now...

Comment: If you look at the left hand side of the page you should see "Manage Resources", this has all the JS and CSS. The page just shows JQM native layout for grouping

Comment: OK, I see the js now, which is just a link to my js. When you say "is this what you wanted the key layout to do", I don't know what "this" refers to. Other than the JQM default layout for a bunch of buttons, which is not what I want.